# Updating an entry on MediaStore does not work on Android Q / API29

Tags: java, android, android-10.0

I am trying (without luck) to update entries for MediaStore for both audio tracks and images. I am using something like this:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, title);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.YEAR, year);

resolver.update(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values, MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + "= ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) })
```

The above snippet works on API16->API28 without problems.

Though, on API29 it does not work. No errors are displayed on logs or messages. I am trying the above code on the API29 emulator. I am not sure if this issue is related to using an emulator or not.

I would really appreciate any information that points me in the right direction.

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? What are your specific symptoms? Also, is this for a piece of content that you added via `insert()` or that some other app added?

Comment: Thanks for taking an interest in this, CommonsWare. On API 16-28, the update statement returns 1 entry affected and the update is carried out. On API29 it returns 0 and no rows are affected. No errors or messages are displayed on my logs at all. I query all music collection on app start and I allow for changing some information regarding the tracks. I do not insert those records myself.

Comment: What permissions do you hold? I have not tried modifying `MediaStore` entries that I have not created myself in Android Q.

Comment: I have `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and also put `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in my manifest. I also request the write permission on start on Android M+ devices.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have created a playlist using my app and tried to rename it (also using my app). That did not work either. Really odd behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60152702/786656 worked for me.

You need to call `update` once with the flag `IS_PENDING` set to 1. Then you call `update` again with the modified values you want and the flag `IS_PENDING` set to 0.