# How to update metadata of audio file in Android Q media store?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, mediastore, android-music-player, android-10.0

Updating metadata of audio file in media store is not working in Android Q OS, it works in all other OS.

I am using content provider with uri specified as MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI. It is working fine in all below Android Q device. Below is the code that I am using to update track metadata.

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

cv.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, newTitle);
cv.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM, newAlbumName);
cv.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, newArtistName);

int rowsUpdated = resolver.update(uri, cv, 
MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{audioId});
```

For Android Q device, rowsUpdated is always 0 with no exception.
How are other music player updating tracks metadata in Android Q ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally, it took some time but I figured that out.

First, you need to obtain access to file. [Here you can read about that](https://developer.android.google.cn/training/data-storage/shared/media?hl=en#update-other-apps-files)

Next, I found out that to update title or artist fields (maybe others to, I didn't test them) you need to set column `MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING` value to 1. Like that:

```
    val id = //Your audio file id

    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)

    val uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id)
    contentResolver.update(uri, values, null, null)
```

And then you can edit fields that you need. Also to end the update process set `MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING` to 0 again:

```
    val id = //Your audio file id
    val title = //New title
    val artist = //New artist

    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, title)
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, artist)

    val uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id)
    contentResolver.update(uri, values, null, null)
```

So in one function, it would look like this:

```
    @RequiresApi(value = android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    fun updateMetadata(contentResolver: ContentResolver, id: Long, title: String, artist: String) {
        val uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id)
        val values = ContentValues()
        
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
        contentResolver.update(uri, values, null, null)
        
        values.clear()
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, title)
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, artist)
        contentResolver.update(uri, values, null, null)
    }
```

It's written in Kotlin but I think you will figure out how to do that in java.

**UPDATE**

By updating `MediaStore` you don't updating real file at any android version. That means, if a file would be updated (for example: renamed) and/or scanned by `MediaScannerConnection` your changes will be lost. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60066961/12873009) is right.

Comment: I am not able to find IS_PENDING column in MediaStore.Audio.Media.

Comment: @Velu: Make sure that your `compileSdkVersion` is set to `29` or higher.

Comment: Your answer is actually right. Although you probably don't change some meta-data or data when not writing to the file, updating via ContentResolver might touch the real file in Android Q if for example the `DISPLAY_NAME` changes. This is considered a placement changing column and does not require `PENDING` status. Most columns though require `PENDING` status. See MediaProvider implementation's `sMutableColumns` for all columns that do not require `PENDING` status

Comment: This worked for me. And if I opt-out of scoped storage then I didn't have to get access to the file using RecoverableSecurityException, in fact the exception doesn't get thrown, it worked with out that.  However the same things doesn't work for album, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62277997/4732846

Comment: not working on not self (not own) audio files in API >= Q

Answer (score 5):

Using Android Q and beyond you have to first get the file

i.e

```
resolver.openInputStream(uri)?.use { stream -> outputFile.copyInputStreamToFile(stream) }
return outputFile.absolutePath
```

Helper Function

```
private fun File.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream: InputStream?) {
    this.outputStream().use { fileOut ->
        inputStream?.copyTo(fileOut)
    }
}
```

Then alter the metadata via a third party, I use J Audio Tagger

Then over write the old file

```
// From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider
// String: Access mode for the file. May be
// "r" for read-only access,
// "w" for write-only access (erasing whatever data is currently in the file),
// "wa" for write-only access to append to any existing data,
// "rw" for read and write access on any existing data, and
// "rwt" for read and write access that truncates any existing file. This value must never be null.

mContext.application.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri, "w")?.use { stream ->
            stream.write(file.readBytes())
        }
```

This works fine when the file was created by your app

Comment: If you please share some info: 

The version of J Audio Tagger, targetSdkVersion, compileSdkVersion?

Comment: org:jaudiotagger:2.0.3,
compileSdkVersion 29,
targetSdkVersion 29

Answer (score 2):

I've been updating meta data in the MediaStore through a ContentResolver, but this no longer works with Android Q (API 29). The following code gives me a warning, and the description is not updated:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Some text");

res = getContext().getContentResolver().update(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        values,
        MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "= ?", new String[]{sImageId});
```

> android.process.media W/MediaProvider: Ignoring mutation of
>   description from com.example.android.someapp.app

This Medium post describes [how Google has changed the API for accessing and updating files](https://proandroiddev.com/working-with-scoped-storage-8a7e7cafea3), but what about updating just the *meta data*? The warning seems to tell me Google no longer wants to allow third party apps to use the MediaStore, and I also found where the warning comes from: 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/MediaProvider/+/master/src/com/android/providers/media/MediaProvider.java#2960

Comment: Please also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60366394/cant-update-mediastore-on-android-10