# Can't update MediaStore on Android 10

Tags: android, mediastore, android-10.0

I've been updating meta data in the MediaStore through a ContentResolver, but this no longer works with Android Q (API 29). The following code gives me a warning, and the description is not updated:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Some text");

int res = getContext().getContentResolver().update(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        values,
        MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "= ?", new String[]{sImageId});
```

> android.process.media W/MediaProvider: Ignoring mutation of
>   description from com.example.android.someapp.app

This Medium post describes [how Google has changed the API for accessing and updating files](https://proandroiddev.com/working-with-scoped-storage-8a7e7cafea3), but what about updating just the *meta data*? The warning seems to tell me Google no longer wants to allow third party apps to use the MediaStore, and I also found where the warning comes from: 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/MediaProvider/+/master/src/com/android/providers/media/MediaProvider.java#2960

Does anyone know why the update is not working on Android 10, and what is the proper workaround?

Comment: Did you `insert()` the content into the `MediaStore` from this app? Or is this content from some other app?

Comment: This is meta data on images from all folders (buckets) on the device; mainly the camera app. So, no, not content belonging to or originating from my app. I see where you're going with this, is this a policy change with Android because this works fine in previous versions of Android. Is there some technical workaround, or is this just no longer possible? My thinking is, the descriptions "belong" to the images. My app only facilitates, makes it easy to enter a caption. The text should not be private to my app.

Comment: Oh, for context, my app is a gallery type app which shows all images on the device and lets the user enter a description (caption), which is stored on the device (i.e. in the MediaStore) and in the JPEGs (EXIF tags). It's for making a photo book, for example.

Comment: Personally, I haven't tried `update()` for content created by another app yet in the new `MediaStore`. My understanding was that attempts to do that would trigger a `RecoverableSecurityException`. You can use details in that exception to raise a system UI to allow the user to grant you permission to do whatever it was that you were trying to do. I wrote about that [here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/01/05/scoped-storage-stories-modify-content-other-app.html), using [this sample app](https://github.com/android/storage-samples/blob/master/MediaStore) from Google as the basis.

Comment: However, that sample does a `delete()`, not an `update()`, so it is possible that `update()` is different somehow. But, if you have that `update()` wrapped in a `try`/`catch` structure, see if you are catching a `RecoverableSecurityException`. If you are, that is your way forward for getting the rights to modify what you are trying to modify.

Comment: It's not throwing any errors, just that warning... Thanks for the link, though I believe I have encountered your blog while trying to Google this problem recently :) Perhaps I might bother you to do a small experiment on update, since you're already deep in the new MediaStore technicalities?

Comment: SDKINT-29: Trying to update the file which is self-create by the app: Issue: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Movement of content://media/external/file/70 which isn't part of well-defined collection not allowed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, with the help of joakimk, I found the problem.

To update an individual piece of content, you need to use a `Uri` that points to that individual piece of content:

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, text);

    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imgId);

    int res = getContentResolver().update(uri, values, null, null);
```

This form of `update()` will throw a `RecoverableSecurityException`. You can catch that and [raise a system dialog](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#update-other-apps-files) that should give you the permission to successfully update this content.

Basically, the logic that decides whether to throw a `RecoverableSecurityException` depends on the `Uri` itself having the ID of the content, rather than it being in a `WHERE` clause. A side effect of this is that you cannot modify more than one piece of content at a time, though the new Android R APIs for that may help.

I tested this on Android 10 and Android R DP1.

Comment: Is there another way so that we can update multiple rows in mediastore? I'm trying to update title, artist, album, album art and genre.

Comment: Any idea why this is supposed to work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60152702 apparently using MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING solves the problem but not sure what this means.

Comment: @VinceVD: "Is there another way so that we can update multiple rows in mediastore?" -- your list is of columns, not rows, at least as `MediaStore` expresses itself. For multiple columns, include all of them in the `ContentValues`. However, it appears that you may not be able to update some of those things, except *maybe* for content that you originally downloaded. "Any idea why this is supposed to work?" -- I would not expect that to have an impact, but I might try it sometime.

Comment: What about using android:requestLegacyExternalStorage=”true", is this a solution or not recommended to use?

Comment: @VinceVD: On Android 10, you can use it for a few more months. Once your `targetSdkVersion` reaches 29, though, it won't work. It also has nothing much to do with `MediaStore`.

Comment: Even when i query MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI for the column MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID i get an Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column DISTINCT album_id. Why are some columns accessable and some are not? for title, artist, genre it works fine on Android 10. I'm not sure what is happening because my app worked fine till Android pie and now some things don't work anymore.

Comment: @VinceVD: Well, using SQL keywords like `DISTINCT` was always risky. You are making assumptions about both the underlying database structure *and* what sorts of syntax the provider would support. But, beyond that, a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve] might get you some answers.

Comment: See MediaProvider implementation's `sMutableColumns` for all columns not requiring `PENDING` status in Android Q. For all others `PENDING` status is required by the QueryBuilder

Comment: @CodeRed: Thanks! For others, [here is the `master` version of `MediaProvider`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/MediaProvider/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android/providers/media/MediaProvider.java).

Comment: Trying to update the file which is self-create by the app: Issue: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Movement of content://media/external/file/70 which isn't part of well-defined collection not allowed

Comment: @jazzbpn have you found the answer? I am facing the same problem. Don't know why

Comment: This should help you.

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, text);

    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imgId);

    int res = getContentResolver().update(uri, values, null, null);

Answer (score 1):

Do not attempt to update the value in _data or remove the line when creating an image:

values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, path);