# Update DATE_MODIFIED in MediaStore on Android 11 with DocumentFile TreeUri

Tags: android, mediastore, android-11, storage-access-framework, documentfile

I'm struggling to update metadata in the mediastore with a DocumentFile/TreeUri.
This is how I tried to do it:

```
boolean canWrite = documentFile.canWrite(); //returns true

Uri mediaUri = MediaStore.getMediaUri(context, documentFile.getUri());

ContentValuesvalues = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED, newLastModified);

boolean success = context.getContentResolver().update(mediaUri, values,null, null) > 0;
```

It fails and the logcat reads:

*W/MediaProvider: Ignoring mutation of date_modified*

What am I doing wrong? The DocumentFile is writable, it is received via Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE and takePersistableUriPermission was called on the folder.
I also tried updating the entry with IS_PENDING before and removed after:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 1);

boolean success = context.getContentResolver().update(mediaUri, values,
        null, null) > 0; //returns false
```

returns for whatever reason also false, but I see that the file is prefixed with .pendingxxxx, so it seemed to work

```
ContentValuesvalues = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED, newLastModified);
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 0);

boolean success = context.getContentResolver().update(mediaUri, values,null, null) > 0; //returns false
```

Comment: Please give an example of the value of mediaUri.toString().

Comment: `W/MediaProvider: Ignoring mutation of date_modified` That is a warning that the provider would not do what you wanted. No error. You could try with enabling permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: Have you ever tried to update the meta from a file you inser()ted yourself? Please try.

Comment: Did you read? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60366394/cant-update-mediastore-on-android-10

Comment: Search for 'Ignoring mutation of' in: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/MediaProvider/+/master/src/com/android/providers/media/MediaProvider.java  There is MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE too.

Comment: Indeed it works when using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Google didn't accept by application to use it though. Said I should use the mediastore and SAF API in my app instead. Great. Yes I read the oder SO link before. My app has already write access on that file though and no exception is thrown either.

Comment: Okay, here is the issue:  
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/MediaProvider/+/master/src/com/android/providers/media/MediaProvider.java#6361

// Column values controlled by media scanner aren't writable by
// apps, since any edits here don't reflect the metadata on
// disk, and they'd be overwritten during a rescan.

Comment: If edited than metadata on disk should be adapted too of course.

Comment: Yeah, but the way to go should be editing the file modified date first, then run the media scanner on that file to update the mediastore data. Raw file access needs MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions with the now enforced Android 11 API in the playstore. Google deniged me using that permission and suggested me to use the media store api. but obviously that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Indexed value of File#lastModified() extracted from this media item.
This constant represents a column name that can be used with a ContentProvider through a ContentValues or Cursor object. The values stored in this column are Cursor#FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER , and are read-only and cannot be mutated.

[doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html#DATE_MODIFIED)

you can't update this,just use File.setLastModified